# Constrait unique Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Estou com uma dúvida, quando eu crio uma `CONSTRAINT` `UNIQUE` , ela avalia todas as colunas juntas?

Por exemplo,  eu quero que um pais não tenha **nomes** ou **siglas** iguais, nesse caso eu devo criar `CONSTRAINT` diferentes?

Pois eu fiz em apenas uma, ela deixa eu inserir países desde que nome e sigla não sejam iguais, porém, eu quero bloquear ate no caso de apenas uma dessas colunas serem iguais.

Eu fiz assim:

```
CREATE TABLE PAIS
(
  IdPais INTEGER NOT NULL,
  NomePais VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
  SiglaPais VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
  StatusPais CHAR(1) NOT NULL, 
  CONSTRAINT PAIS PRIMARY KEY (IdPais),
  CONSTRAINT PAIS_UNIQUE UNIQUE (NomePais, SiglaPais)
);
/
CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ_ID_PAIS
MINVALUE 1
MAXVALUE 9999999999
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1
NOCACHE
CYCLE;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_ID_PAIS BEFORE INSERT ON PAIS FOR EACH ROW BEGIN <<COLUMN_SEQUENCES>> BEGIN IF :NEW.IDPAIS IS NULL THEN SELECT SEQ_ID_PAIS.NEXTVAL INTO :NEW.IDPAIS FROM DUAL; END IF; END COLUMN_SEQUENCES; END;
/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No caso de:

```
CONSTRAINT PAIS_UNIQUE UNIQUE (NomePais, SiglaPais)
```

As colunas serão analisadas juntas sim, o que resultará em:

```
'Brasil' | 'BR' <- Permitido
'Brasil' | 'BR' <- Violação
'Brazil' | 'BR' <- Permitido
```

Agora Para:

```
CONSTRAINT PAIS_UNIQUE UNIQUE (SiglaPais)

'Brasil' | 'BR' <- Permitido
'Brasil' | 'BR' <- Violação
'Brazil' | 'BR' <- Violação
```

Comment: então, quando eu quiser separado, devo fazer uma constraint para cada coluna, correto ?

Comment: sim, se a determinada coluna não pode repetir o valor em nenhuma condição, a constraint é individual

Comment: SiglaPais poderia ser a PK então.

Comment: dependendo do caso, sim, mas não dá pra saber a especificação do software do colega, então nem entrei nessa questão.